# What is the use of strings like "-*- Mode: Python -*-" found at the top of some python files?

Tags: python

Here are the top few lines (all comments) from a python application. What do the first two comment lines indicate? Are they special markers for another app?

> # -*- Mode: Python -*-
> # vi:si:et:sw=4:sts=4:ts=4
> # 
> # Istanbul - A desktop recorder
> # Copyright (C) 2005 Zaheer Abbas Merali (zaheerabbas at merali dot org)
> # Portions Copyright (C) 2004,2005 Fluendo, S.L. (www.fluendo.com).
> # All rights reserved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line is an emacs thing (although it may also be a vi thing).  It basically tells it that it should use python-mode to read the file.  You'll usually see this if the file ends in an extension other than .py.

As mentioned, the second line deals with spacings.

Comment: Just for clarity, line 1 is an emacs "mode line", line 2 is a vi mode line.  (That file has apparently been edited by user(s) of both editors.)

Answer (score 2):

Its define tab size 4 spaces to text editors like **vi**